# Matching 2 ArrayLists of objects based on their member variables

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Let's say I have 2 objects, Object1 and Object2. Their basic structure is as follows:

**Object 1**

```
int id
String email
```

**Object 2**

```
int id
ArrayList<String> emails
```

Now I have 2 ArrayLists, one of Object1 and Object2. What's an efficient way to find matches where Object 1's email is contained inside Object 2's emails ArrayList and then store their ids in a HashMap (or any other data structure that holds 2 ints)?

I know the obvious and basic solution is to brute force it with 2 for loops, like this:

```
ArrayList<Object1> obj1List;
ArrayList<Object2> obj2List;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> idMapping = new HashMap()<>;

for (Object1 obj1 : obj1List){
    String obj1Email = obj1.getEmail();
    for (Object2 obj2 : obj2List){
        ArrayList<String> obj2EmailList = obj2.getEmails();
        if(obj2EmailList.contains(obj1Email)){
            int obj1Id = obj1.getId();
            int obj2Id = obj2.getId();
            idMapping.put(obj1Id, obj2Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Each ArrayList has around a thousand objects, so performance really isn't that big of an issue. However, I'm sure there's much more elegant ways of solving this problems. I'm guessing it might be possible using streams, but I'm not familiar enough with them to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're stuck with `ArrayList` then from a performance standpoint this is about as good as you're going to get. Streams may potentially make the code shorter but it won't make it faster.

Comment: Keep the iterative solution, which is more readable and outperforms streams solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are doing is absolutely fine. However, if you want to use `streams`, you can try this approach.

Since you are going to traverse across the `List` of `Object2` pretty frequently for every `Object1`, I would recommend creating a `Map` for `Object2 List` so that your retrieval is faster.

Based on your code, I think I can map each email to it's individual id **assuming** an `email` in `Object2 List` can `never have more than 1 id` which I think is `true` based on your implementation.

If my assumption is wrong, there is nothing much we can do.

Here is the code:

```
Map<String, Integer> obj2Map = new HashMap<>();
for (Object2 obj2 : obj2List) {
    int id = obj2.getId();
    obj2Map.putAll(
            obj2.getEmails()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, email -> id))
    );
}

Map<Integer, Integer> idMapping = new HashMap();
for (Object1 obj1 : obj1List) {
    if (obj2Map.containsKey(obj1.getEmail())) {
        idMapping.put(obj1.getId(), obj2Map.get(obj1.getEmail()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend replacing weird code inside the first loop with `for (String email : obj2.getEmails()) obj2Map.put(email, obj2.getId());`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> collect = object1List.stream()
                .flatMap(ob1 -> object2List.stream().filter(ob2 -> ob2.getEmails().contains(ob1.getEmail())).map(ob2 -> {
                    int [] arr = new int[2];
                    arr[0] = ob1.getId();
                    arr[1] = ob2.getId();
                    return arr;
                }))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> arr[1]));
```

you could use **flatMap** to flatten the list of emails in the second Object and compare to the first object using ArrayList contains method.

the above code is the stream version of your code however there could possibly be duplicate keys in the map.

Answer (score 0):

As `idMapping` I would recommend use `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`. There could be more ids in `obj2List` witch the same email. For example with this data:

```java
List<Object1> obj1List = Arrays.asList(
        new Object1(1, "a"),
        new Object1(2, "b"),
        new Object1(3, "c"));
List<Object2> obj2List = Arrays.asList(
        new Object2(11, "a"),
        new Object2(12, "a", "b"),
        new Object2(14, "c", "d"),
        new Object2(15, "e", "f")
        );
```

When `HashMap<Integer, Integer> idMapping` you get:

```
{1=12, 2=12, 3=14}
```

But for `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> idMapping` it will be:

```
{1=[11, 12], 2=[12], 3=[14]}
```

The main solution could be like below. Create map (grouping by email) and then use it to create `idMapping` :

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> idsForEmailFromObj2List = obj2List.stream().
        flatMap(obj2 -> obj2.getEmails().stream().map(
                email -> new Object1(obj2.getId(), email)
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Object1::getEmail,
        Collectors.mapping(Object1::getId, Collectors.toList())));

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> idMapping = obj1List.stream()
        .filter(obj1 -> idsForEmailFromObj2List.containsKey(obj1.getEmail()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Object1::getId, 
                obj1 -> idsForEmailFromObj2List.get(obj1.getEmail())));
```